# Consuming an API with authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a library which consumes the Imgur API.

This is the main file.

```
var request = require('request-promise'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

var Imgur = function(options) {

    this.options = {};

    if (typeof options.clientId === 'undefined' || !options.clientId) {
        throw new Error('No client ID specified, register one at "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient"');
    }

    if (typeof options.clientSecret !== 'undefined') {
        this.options.clientSecret = options.clientSecret;
    }

    this.options.clientId = options.clientId;
    this.options.version = options.version || 3;
    this.options.endPoint = 'https://api.imgur.com/' + this.options.version + '/';

    fs
        .readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, './endpoints'))
        .forEach(function(file) {
            if (~file.indexOf('.js')) {
                this[file.substring(0, file.indexOf('.'))] = require(path.join(__dirname, './endpoints', file))(this);
            }
        }.bind(this));
};

Imgur.prototype.extend = function(target, source) {
    var extended = {};
    for (var prop in target) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(target, prop)) {
            extended[prop] = target[prop];
        }
    }
    for (var prop in source) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)) {
            extended[prop] = source[prop];
        }
    }
    return extended;
};

Imgur.prototype.request = function(method, path, params) {
    params = params || {};
    if (typeof method === 'undefined' || ['get', 'post', 'head', 'delete'].indexOf(method.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
        throw new Error('no method specified or method isn\'t in [get, post, head, delete]');
    }
    var options = {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Client-ID ' + this.options.clientId
        },
        json: true
    };
    if (typeof params.data !== 'undefined' && method.toLowerCase() !== 'get') {
        options.form = params.data;
    }
    if (typeof params.file !== 'undefined') {
        options.formData = params.file;
    }
    if (typeof params.access_token !== 'undefined') {
        options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + params.access_token;
    }
    for (var key in params) {
        if (['data', 'file', 'access_token'].indexOf(key) != -1)
            continue;
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            path = path.replace(new RegExp('\{' + key + '\}', 'g'), params[key]);
        }
    }
    options.url = /^https?:\/\//.test(path) ? path : this.options.endPoint + path;
    return request(options);
};

module.exports = Imgur;
```

It is then extended with endpoints such as:

```
var stream = require('stream');

var Image = function(imgur) {

    this.image = function(params) {
        params = params || {};
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            throw new Error('id required');
        }
        var options = imgur.extend(params, {
            id: params.id
        });
        return imgur.request('get', 'image/{id}', options);
    };

    this.upload = function(params) {
        params = params || {};
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty('image')) {
            throw new Error('image required, can be a binary file, base64 data or a URL');
        }
        var options = imgur.extend(params, {
            data: params.data,
            file: params.file
        });
        if (typeof params.file === 'string') {
            if (/https?:\/\//.test(params.file)) {
                options.data.file = 'URL';
            } else {
                options.data.type = 'base64';
            }
        } else if (params.file instanceof stream.Stream) {
            options.data.type = 'file'
        }
        return imgur.request('post', 'image', options);
    };

    this.delete = function(params) {
        params = params || {};
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            throw new Error('id required');
        }
        var options = imgur.extend(params, {
            id: params.id
        });
        return imgur.request('delete', 'image/{id}', options);
    };

    this.update = function(params) {
        params = params || {};
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            throw new Error('id required');
        }
        var options = imgur.extend(params, {
            id: params.id,
            data: params.data
        });
        return imgur.request('post', 'image/{id}', options);
    };

    this.favorite = function(params) {
        params = params || {};
        if (!params.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            throw new Error('id required');
        }
        var options = imgur.extend(params, {
            id: params.id
        });
        return imgur.request('post', 'image/{id}/favorite', options);
    };

    return this;

};

module.exports = Image;
```

There is an oauth endpoint that looks like this.

```
var Oauth = function(imgur) {

    this.getOauthUrl = function() {
        return 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=' + imgur.options.clientId + '&response_type=code';
    };

    this.authorizeCallback = function(authCode) {
        if (typeof authCode === "undefined" || !authCode) {
            throw new Error('authorization code required');
        }
        var options = {
            data: {
                client_id: imgur.options.clientId,
                client_secret: imgur.options.clientSecret,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                code: authCode
            }
        };
        return imgur.request('post', 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token', options).then(function(data) {
            data.expiresAt = Math.round(Date.now() + (data.expires_in * 1000));
            return data;
        });
    };

    this.refreshToken = function(refreshToken) {
        if (typeof refreshToken === "undefined" || !refreshToken) {
            throw new Error('No refresh token defined');
        }
        var options = {
            data: {
                client_id: imgur.options.clientId,
                client_secret: imgur.options.clientSecret,
                grant_type: 'refresh_token',
                refresh_token: refreshToken
            }
        };
        return imgur.request('post', 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token', options).then(function(data) {
            data.expiresAt = Math.round(Date.now() + (data.expires_in * 1000));
            return data;
        });
    };

    return this;

};

module.exports = Oauth;
```

It is all pulled together with the following code.

```
var Imgur = require('./imgurjs');
var imgur = new Imgur({
    clientId: '<clientid>',
    clientSecret: '<clientsecret>'
});
```

An example of using it would be

```
imgur.image.favourite({id: 1})
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

You can authenticate using the oauth like so (example uses express)

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(imgur.oauth.getOauthUrl());
});

app.get('/loginCallback', function(req, res) {
    imgur.oauth.authorizeCallback(req.query.code).then(function(user) {
        req.session.user = user;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Then you can access authenticated routes by passing in the token stored in the session

```
imgur.image.delete(imgur.extend({id: 1}, req.session.user))
//or imgur.image.delete({id: 1, access_token: req.session.user.access_token})
    .then(function(response) {

    });
```

I feel that there's a better way to do this rather than passing the oauth token to every method, but I can't get my head around it.

Is there a way to have it so I only need to call the constructor once to instantiate the client id and secret, but also have an instance for each user's session which would store their oauth token.

Comment: by the way, please don't modify the code in your question after receiving answers (unless it's to fix something silly like a typo)

Comment: @DanPantry Sorry, I was just adding an alternative way to pass the oauth token in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: just giving fair warning :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short review ahead - I'll post a longer one during my lunch break if no one else has.

You mention this:

> I feel that there's a better way to do this rather than passing the oauth token to every method, but I can't get my head around it.

I don't have enough time (before lunch) to look over this and learn the API enough to fully review it, but  you could try something like this:

```
module.exports = (function() {
  return function(token) {
    var favourite = function() {
      // use the token in some manner
    };

    return {
      favourite: favourite
    };
  }
}());

var Image = require('./image');
var image = Image(oauthToken);
image.favourite();
```

This will mean you only ever have to pass the token in once. The downside is that you won't be able to automatically 'refresh' a token - the user will have to invoke the exported function again to refresh the token (or you could add a method on the image export to do this as well)

Comment: Just an FYI, there's more than one endpoint. (gallery/album/account) etc. There are too many to post in the question though.

Comment: I'd also like to call everything from the constructor. So `imgur.image(oauthToken).favourite()` maybe.

Comment: That's what this code sample addresses. You could easily make `imgur.image = Image`, where `Image` is as it is in the code sample above - ie, a function that takes `oauthToken`. :-)

Yeah, I gathered there is more than one endpoint.